# resize() function not working on resize but on refresh

Tags: jquery, resize, window-resize

I have this simple jQuery to change the height of the footer on the window resize, but it is working on refresh not on resize.

```html
<script>
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').outerHeight();
    $('#footer').height(footerHeight);
    $('#content').css({
      'paddingBottom': footerHeight + 'px'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It seems no problem in your code, i use resize like this too, could you please also include the html?

Comment: ^ Indded, seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/cy7zm45j/. Note that your CSS may be the problem. It would help to see a full working example

Comment: working demo
https://jsfiddle.net/yhhgfjzh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using the event in a correct way, try this:

```
<script>
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').outerHeight();
    $('#footer').height(footerHeight);
    $('#content').css({
      'paddingBottom': footerHeight + 'px'
    });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you sure that your code will work? Please add an explanation that why it is going to work? BTW your code is identical to OP's code

Comment: Not identical because he is not using the event element "on", that's why when he resize the screen nothing happen but only on the refresh

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://jsfiddle.net/yhhgfjzh/ 
This is the working demo before adding "on".
just resize and see the content of the footer is going out the footer.
now add "on" and resize, you will see the difference.